# flex 3: RadioButtonGroups - multiple groups of independent radio buttons

Tags: apache-flex, radio-button

I tried to search, but I couldn't find what I was looking for... so sorry if this is a repost.

I need to create 10 separate radio button groups, each with three options (show, collapse, or hide).  I've created the following:

```
<mx:HBox>
    <mx:Text text="Directors Prep." width="125" />
    <mx:RadioButtonGroup id="dprepRB" enabled="false" />
    <mx:RadioButton id="dprepshow" label="Show" value="1" groupName="{dprepRB}" />
    <mx:RadioButton id="dprepcollapse" label="Collapse" value="0" groupName="{dprepRB}" />
    <mx:RadioButton id="dprephide" label="Hide" value="-1" groupName="{dprepRB}" selected="true" />
</mx:HBox>

<mx:HBox>
    <mx:Text text="Check In/Out" width="125" />
    <mx:RadioButtonGroup id="checkIORB" enabled="false" />
    <mx:RadioButton id="checkioshow" label="Show" value="1" groupName="{checkIORB}" />
    <mx:RadioButton id="checkiocollapse" label="Collapse" value="0" groupName="{checkIORB}" />
    <mx:RadioButton id="checkiohide" label="Hide" value="-1" groupName="{checkIORB}" selected="true" />
</mx:HBox>

... and so on with the other 8 groups
```

On load, I would like the "Hide" button to be selected.  However, when the application loads, only the hide button on the last group is selected.  If I select any other button on any other group, the "Hide" button from the last group is deselected, and the button I clicked becomes the only selected radio button.  It seems like, for some reason, flex is thinking all the radio buttons belong to the same group.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Brds

Comment: Just a guess: shouldn't the 'groupName' be a name (i.e. a String) instead of a bound RadioButtonGroup?

Comment: Yep... all the tutorials i read had it in {} brackets... dunno why.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use:

```
<mx:HBox>
    <mx:Text text="Directors Prep." width="125" />
    <mx:RadioButtonGroup id="dprepRB" enabled="false" />
    <mx:RadioButton id="dprepshow" label="Show" value="1" group="{dprepRB}" />
    <mx:RadioButton id="dprepcollapse" label="Collapse" value="0" group="{dprepRB}" />
    <mx:RadioButton id="dprephide" label="Hide" value="-1" group="{dprepRB}" selected="true" />
</mx:HBox>
```

See details [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/RadioButton.html#group).

Comment: What did you change?  I can't spot the difference(s).

Comment: Did you followed all the links in my answer?

Comment: @Brds he changed 'groupName' to 'group' and then it works with the binding

Answer (score 1):

Hi my solution was to define the RadioButtonGroup is the declarations tag block:

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <mx:RadioButtonGroup id="dprepRB"/>
</fx:Declarations>
```

And then use the group later on in the HBox or whatever:

```
<mx:HBox>
    <mx:Text text="Directors Prep." width="125" />
    <mx:RadioButton id="dprepshow" label="Show" value="1" group="{dprepRB}" />
    <mx:RadioButton id="dprepcollapse" label="Collapse" value="0" group="{dprepRB}" />
    <mx:RadioButton id="dprephide" label="Hide" value="-1" group="{dprepRB}" selected="true" />
</mx:HBox>
```

You should use group="" not groupname="". Then each independent radio button group can be selected.

Cheers